# Any way to synchronize CSS transitions with touch events (swipe)?

Tags: javascript, css, touch, css-transitions, swipe

For example, if the swipe is slower, transition speed should also slow down.

If this is not possible with only CSS, what would be the least painful way to approach this with javascript? Essentially I'm trying to avoid declaring the transition rules in javascript.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using js ? It would perfectly fit in your situation, which is an interaction case. The only way to use CSS only would be with classes, but it would be inaccurate by design (especially if the duration range is wide, you would need dozens of classes). So if it's a matter of "animations musn't be made with javascript" just don't bother. Anyway the number you get from the touch event is given by javascript, there is nothing wrong with using this number for a consequence of this action, even if it's an animation.

Answer (score 1):

You could stablish the rules for the transition in CSS (transition-property, transition-delay and transition-timing-function), and use javascript just to set transition-duration. This way everything is set up in CSS except the duration, which is what you want.

Comment: This helped me, I like to avoid javascript when possible for appearance related behaviors, but when just a little is necessary-its good to know where to start